# colourful polylines in android maps api v2

Tags: android, polyline, linear-gradients, android-maps-v2

I want to draw polyline in android maps api version 2. I want it to have many colors, preferably with gradients. It seems to me though, that polylines are allowed to have only single color. 
How can I do that? I already have api-v1 overlay drawing what I like, so presumably I can reuse some code

```
public class RouteOverlayGoogle extends Overlay {
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
       //(...) draws line with color representing speed
    }
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: sadly no, that project was finished without this feature

Answer (score 8):

I know it's been a pretty long time since this has been asked, **but there are still no gradient polylines** (as of writing, ~may 2015) and drawing multiple polylines really doesn't cut it (jagged edges, quite a bit of lag when dealing with several hundred of points, just not very visually appealing).

When I had to implement gradient polylines, what I ended up doing was implementing a `TileOverlay` that would render the polyline to a canvas and then rasterize it (see this gist for the specific code I wrote to do it https://gist.github.com/Dagothig/5f9cf0a4a7a42901a7b2).

The implementation doesn't try to do any sort of viewport culling because I ended up not needing it to reach the performance I wanted (I'm not sure about the numbers, but it was under a second per tiles, and multiple tiles will be rendered at the same time).

Rendering the gradient polyline can be pretty tricky to get properly however since you're dealing with varying viewports (positions and size): more than that, I hit a few issues with the limit on float precision at high zoom levels (20+). In the end I didn't use the scale and translate functions from the canvas because I would get weird corruption issues.

Something else to watch out for if you use a similar data structure to what I had (latitudes, longitudes and timestamps) is that you need multiple segments to render the gradient properly (I ended up working with 3 points at a time).

For posterity's sake, I'm going to also leave the code from the gist here:
(the projections are done using https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils if you're wondering where `com.google.maps.android.projection.SphericalMercatorProjection` comes from)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Tile;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileProvider;
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;
import com.google.maps.android.geometry.Point;
import com.google.maps.android.projection.SphericalMercatorProjection;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Tile overlay used to display a colored polyline as a replacement for the non-existence of gradient
 * polylines for google maps
 */
public class ColoredPolylineTileOverlay<T extends ColoredPolylineTileOverlay.PointHolder> implements TileProvider {

    public static final double LOW_SPEED_CLAMP_KMpH = 0;
    public static final double LOW_SPEED_CLAMP_MpS = 0;
    // TODO: calculate speed as highest speed of pointsCollection
    public static final double HIGH_SPEED_CLAMP_KMpH = 50;
    public static final double HIGH_SPEED_CLAMP_MpS = HIGH_SPEED_CLAMP_KMpH * 1000 / (60 * 60);
    public static final int BASE_TILE_SIZE = 256;

    public static int[] getSpeedColors(Context context) {
        return new int[] {
                context.getResources().getColor(R.color.polyline_low_speed),
                context.getResources().getColor(R.color.polyline_med_speed),
                context.getResources().getColor(R.color.polyline_high_speed)
        };
    }

    public static float getSpeedProportion(double metersPerSecond) {
        return (float)(Math.max(Math.min(metersPerSecond, HIGH_SPEED_CLAMP_MpS), LOW_SPEED_CLAMP_MpS) / HIGH_SPEED_CLAMP_MpS);
    }

    public static int interpolateColor(int[] colors, float proportion) {
        int rTotal = 0, gTotal = 0, bTotal = 0;
        // We correct the ratio to colors.length - 1 so that
        // for i == colors.length - 1 and p == 1, then the final ratio is 1 (see below)
        float p = proportion * (colors.length - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            // The ratio mostly resides on the 1 - Math.abs(p - i) calculation :
            // Since for p == i, then the ratio is 1 and for p == i + 1 or p == i -1, then the ratio is 0
            // This calculation works BECAUSE p lies within [0, length - 1] and i lies within [0, length - 1] as well
            float iRatio = Math.max(1 - Math.abs(p - i), 0.0f);
            rTotal += (int)(Color.red(colors[i]) * iRatio);
            gTotal += (int)(Color.green(colors[i]) * iRatio);
            bTotal += (int)(Color.blue(colors[i]) * iRatio);
        }

        return Color.rgb(rTotal, gTotal, bTotal);
    }

    protected final Context context;
    protected final PointCollection<T> pointsCollection;
    protected final int[] speedColors;
    protected final float density;
    protected final int tileDimension;
    protected final SphericalMercatorProjection projection;

    // Caching calculation-related stuff
    protected LatLng[] trailLatLngs;
    protected Point[] projectedPts;
    protected Point[] projectedPtMids;
    protected double[] speeds;

    public ColoredPolylineTileOverlay(Context context, PointCollection pointsCollection) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.pointsCollection = pointsCollection;
        speedColors = getSpeedColors(context);
        density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        tileDimension = (int)(BASE_TILE_SIZE * density);
        projection = new SphericalMercatorProjection(BASE_TILE_SIZE);
        calculatePointsAndSpeeds();
    }
    public void calculatePointsAndSpeeds() {
        trailLatLngs = new LatLng[pointsCollection.getPoints().size()];
        projectedPts = new Point[pointsCollection.getPoints().size()];
        projectedPtMids = new Point[Math.max(pointsCollection.getPoints().size() - 1, 0)];
        speeds = new double[Math.max(pointsCollection.getPoints().size() - 1, 0)];

        List<T> points = pointsCollection.getPoints();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            T point = points.get(i);
            LatLng latLng = point.getLatLng();
            trailLatLngs[i] = latLng;
            projectedPts[i] = projection.toPoint(latLng);

            // Mids
            if (i > 0) {
                LatLng previousLatLng = points.get(i - 1).getLatLng();
                LatLng latLngMid = SphericalUtil.interpolate(previousLatLng, latLng, 0.5);
                projectedPtMids[i - 1] = projection.toPoint(latLngMid);

                T previousPoint = points.get(i - 1);
                double speed = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(latLng, previousLatLng) / ((point.getTime() - previousPoint.getTime()) / 1000.0);
                speeds[i - 1] = speed;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        // Because getTile can be called asynchronously by multiple threads, none of the info we keep in the class will be modified
        // (getTile is essentially side-effect-less) :
        // Instead, we create the bitmap, the canvas and the paints specifically for the call to getTile

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileDimension, tileDimension, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Normally, instead of the later calls for drawing being offset, we would offset them using scale() and translate() right here
        // However, there seems to be funky issues related to float imprecisions that happen at large scales when using this method, so instead
        // The points are offset properly when drawing
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Matrix shaderMat = new Matrix();
        Paint gradientPaint = new Paint();
        gradientPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        gradientPaint.setStrokeWidth(3f * density);
        gradientPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        gradientPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        gradientPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        gradientPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, speedColors, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        gradientPaint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(shaderMat);

        Paint colorPaint = new Paint();
        colorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        colorPaint.setStrokeWidth(3f * density);
        colorPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        colorPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        colorPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        // See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#zoom for handy info regarding what zoom is
        float scale = (float)(Math.pow(2, zoom) * density);

        renderTrail(canvas, shaderMat, gradientPaint, colorPaint, scale, x, y);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        return new Tile(tileDimension, tileDimension, baos.toByteArray());
    }

    public void renderTrail(Canvas canvas, Matrix shaderMat, Paint gradientPaint, Paint colorPaint, float scale, int x, int y) {
        List<T> points = pointsCollection.getPoints();
        double speed1, speed2;
        MutPoint pt1 = new MutPoint(), pt2 = new MutPoint(), pt3 = new MutPoint(), pt1mid2 = new MutPoint(), pt2mid3 = new MutPoint();

        // Guard statement: if the trail is only 1 point, just render the point by itself as a speed of 0
        if (points.size() == 1) {
            pt1.set(projectedPts[0], scale, x, y, tileDimension);
            speed1 = 0;
            float speedProp = getSpeedProportion(speed1);

            colorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            colorPaint.setColor(interpolateColor(speedColors, speedProp));
            canvas.drawCircle((float) pt1.x, (float) pt1.y, colorPaint.getStrokeWidth() / 2f, colorPaint);
            colorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            return;
        }

        // Guard statement: if the trail is exactly 2 points long, just render a line from A to B at d(A, B) / t speed
        if (points.size() == 2) {
            pt1.set(projectedPts[0], scale, x, y, tileDimension);
            pt2.set(projectedPts[1], scale, x, y, tileDimension);
            speed1 = speeds[0];
            float speedProp = getSpeedProportion(speed1);

            drawLine(canvas, colorPaint, pt1, pt2, speedProp);

            return;
        }

        // Because we want to be displaying speeds as color ratios, we need multiple points to do it properly:
        // Since we use calculate the speed using the distance and the time, we need at least 2 points to calculate the distance;
        // this means we know the speed for a segment, not a point.
        // Furthermore, since we want to be easing the color changes between every segment, we have to use 3 points to do the easing;
        // every line is split into two, and we ease over the corners
        // This also means the first and last corners need to be extended to include the first and last points respectively
        // Finally (you can see about that in getTile()) we need to offset the point projections based on the scale and x, y because
        // weird display behaviour occurs
        for (int i = 2; i < points.size(); i++) {
            pt1.set(projectedPts[i - 2], scale, x, y, tileDimension);
            pt2.set(projectedPts[i - 1], scale, x, y, tileDimension);
            pt3.set(projectedPts[i], scale, x, y, tileDimension);

            // Because we want to split the lines in two to ease over the corners, we need the middle points
            pt1mid2.set(projectedPtMids[i - 2], scale, x, y, tileDimension);
            pt2mid3.set(projectedPtMids[i - 1], scale, x, y, tileDimension);

            // The speed is calculated in meters per second (same format as the speed clamps); because getTime() is in millis, we need to correct for that
            speed1 = speeds[i - 2];
            speed2 = speeds[i - 1];
            float speed1Prop = getSpeedProportion(speed1);
            float speed1to2Prop = getSpeedProportion((speed1 + speed2) / 2);
            float speed2Prop = getSpeedProportion(speed2);

            // Circle for the corner (removes the weird empty corners that occur otherwise)
            colorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            colorPaint.setColor(interpolateColor(speedColors, speed1to2Prop));
            canvas.drawCircle((float)pt2.x, (float)pt2.y, colorPaint.getStrokeWidth() / 2f, colorPaint);
            colorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            // Corner
            // Note that since for the very first point and the very last point we don't split it in two, we used them instead.
            drawLine(canvas, shaderMat, gradientPaint, colorPaint, i - 2 == 0 ? pt1 : pt1mid2, pt2, speed1Prop, speed1to2Prop);
            drawLine(canvas, shaderMat, gradientPaint, colorPaint, pt2, i == points.size() - 1 ? pt3 : pt2mid3, speed1to2Prop, speed2Prop);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Note: it is assumed the shader is 0, 0, 1, 0 (horizontal) so that it lines up with the rotation
     * (rotations are usually setup so that the angle 0 points right)
     */
    public void drawLine(Canvas canvas, Matrix shaderMat, Paint gradientPaint, Paint colorPaint, MutPoint pt1, MutPoint pt2, float ratio1, float ratio2) {
        // Degenerate case: both ratios are the same; we just handle it using the colorPaint (handling it using the shader is just messy and ineffective)
        if (ratio1 == ratio2) {
            drawLine(canvas, colorPaint, pt1, pt2, ratio1);
            return;
        }
        shaderMat.reset();

        // PS: don't ask me why this specfic orders for calls works but other orders will mess up
        // Since every call is pre, this is essentially ordered as (or my understanding is that it is):
        // ratio translate -> ratio scale -> scale to pt length -> translate to pt start -> rotate
        // (my initial intuition was to use only post calls and to order as above, but it resulted in odd corruptions)

        // Setup based on points:
        // We translate the shader so that it is based on the first point, rotated towards the second and since the length of the
        // gradient is 1, then scaling to the length of the distance between the points makes it exactly as long as needed
        shaderMat.preRotate((float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(pt2.y - pt1.y, pt2.x - pt1.x)), (float)pt1.x, (float)pt1.y);
        shaderMat.preTranslate((float)pt1.x, (float)pt1.y);
        float scale = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pt2.x - pt1.x, 2) + Math.pow(pt2.y - pt1.y, 2));
        shaderMat.preScale(scale, scale);

        // Setup based on ratio
        // By basing the shader to the first ratio, we ensure that the start of the gradient corresponds to it
        // The inverse scaling of the shader means that it takes the full length of the call to go to the second ratio
        // For instance; if d(ratio1, ratio2) is 0.5, then the shader needs to be twice as long so that an entire call (1)
        // Results in only half of the gradient being used
        shaderMat.preScale(1f / (ratio2 - ratio1), 1f / (ratio2 - ratio1));
        shaderMat.preTranslate(-ratio1, 0);

        gradientPaint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(shaderMat);

        canvas.drawLine(
                (float)pt1.x,
                (float)pt1.y,
                (float)pt2.x,
                (float)pt2.y,
                gradientPaint
        );
    }
    public void drawLine(Canvas canvas, Paint colorPaint, MutPoint pt1, MutPoint pt2, float ratio) {
        colorPaint.setColor(interpolateColor(speedColors, ratio));
        canvas.drawLine(
                (float)pt1.x,
                (float)pt1.y,
                (float)pt2.x,
                (float)pt2.y,
                colorPaint
        );
    }

    public interface PointCollection<T extends PointHolder> {
        List<T> getPoints();
    }
    public interface PointHolder {
        LatLng getLatLng();
        long getTime();
    }
    public static class MutPoint {
        public double x, y;

        public MutPoint set(Point point, float scale, int x, int y, int tileDimension) {
            this.x = point.x * scale - x * tileDimension;
            this.y = point.y * scale - y * tileDimension;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation assumes two relatively large things:

1. the polyline is already complete
2. that there is only one polyline.

I would assume handling (1) would not be very difficult. However, if you intend to draw multiple polylines this way, you may need to look at some ways to enhance performance (keeping a bounding box of the polylines to be able to easily discard those that do not fit the viewport for one).

One more thing to remember regarding using a `TileOverlay` is that it is rendered after movements are done, not during; so you may want to back up the overlay with an actual monochrome polyline underneath it to give it some continuity.

PS: this is the first time I try to answer a question, so if there's anything I should fix or do differently please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! At first glance, your answer seems very good: it's detailed, lots of explanation, well formatted, correct grammar, a code sample and reference links where needed. Keep it up like this and you'll be a good contributor in no time :)

Comment: do you have an example of how to use it?

Comment: it has been a handful of years since and I haven't kept up closely with Android developments, but back then you would handle it the same way you would handle any TileOverlay (part of the Google Maps API would simply let you add tile overlays). The point holder interface really is just a list of timed points that are used to interpolate a gradient. You could strip that info and then simply rewrite the code that calculates where on your gradient each point lies based on a different criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution: draw multiple polylines and individually set the color.

Comment: well, this results in "cracks" between colors, but for now will have to do. Later I think I'll give TileProvider a chance, but it seems like an overkill.