# Google Map Gradient Polylines for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The question of how to do gradient polylines has been asked a number of times, however, I want to know if this comes built in for Android. In the following post, this question is poised and someone answered that as of May 2015, there was still no gradient polylines for Android:

[colourful polylines in android maps api v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258830/colourful-polylines-in-android-maps-api-v2)

I have combed through all the documentation I can find and do not see anything about a gradient polyline function. Am I missing it? Because iOS has had this  capability for three years now.

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2014/02/gradient-polylines-and-structured.html

I can't imagine that Google is prioritizing iOS over Android. Or are they? Here is the documentation I have checked:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be helpful. Or at least confirm that Android has been ignored in respect to gradient polylines.

Comment: Is [this](https://gist.github.com/Dagothig/5f9cf0a4a7a42901a7b2) useful?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I wrote my own class. I can make it public if many others are trying to do the same thing

Comment: @portfoliobuilder can you share it please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this is not implemented yet in Google Maps Android API.

You can see the following feature requests:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828754

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821835

At this point I think Google didn't set a high priority on these tasks. You can star these feature requests to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.

Comment: Crazy! And they even say its a S4 severity, meaning only cosmetic. That is the lowest severity. They will never get around to this feature request for Android. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 3):

It is is available from Maps SDK 3.1.0 (beta): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v310-beta#creating_a_gradient_polyline

Comment: but now is deprecated:) it will be added in new releases