# Gardient polyline in android googlemap

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing application with `Google Maps` , and I want to change the style of `polyline` on map. i want to change the color of polyline to gradient line, how to do this in Android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727912/google-map-gradient-polylines-for-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use my `richmaps` library: https://github.com/antoniocarlon/richmaps

You can easily create a gradient polyline like this:

```
RichPolylineOptions polylineOpts = new RichPolylineOptions(null)
        .zIndex(3) // zIndex represents the position of the polyline on the RichLayer
        .strokeWidth(15)
        .strokeColor(Color.YELLOW) // Set the polyline base color
        .linearGradient(true)
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.22987, -3.95931)).color(Color.RED)) // Set color for some vertices
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23109, -3.95926)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23063, -3.95837)).color(Color.RED))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23169, -3.95809)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23093, -3.95705)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23023, -3.95626)));
RichPolyline polyline = polylineOpts.build();
polyline.add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23163, -3.95602)).color(Color.CYAN)); // RichPoint added after the creation of the RichPolyline
richLayer.addShape(polyline);
```

Comment: i also use this method , getting all the points and making polyline from them , the issue is it take too much load because there are too many polyline some thousands

Answer (score 1):

I was working for a while on a use case for creating a gradient polyline on Google Maps in Android natively since it is not a built-in API in Google Maps Android SDK.

So, I created a Github Repository that discussing the use case, the approach that I took, and how I implement it to show a gradient polyline on Google Maps in Android.

If you are interested in such a topic, please take a look and feel free to reach out or to contribute :)

https://github.com/ahmedadeltito/GradientPolyline

Answer (score 0):

It is available in Google Maps SDK 3.1.0 (beta): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v310-beta#creating_a_gradient_polyline

Answer (score -1):

You can give [this library](https://github.com/Moneemsaadaoui/Gradientpoly) a shot if you're looking for accurate drawing and tracking

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/akexorcist/googledirection/GoogleDirection;
        at com.rrdl.gradientpoly.GradientPoly.DrawPolyline(GradientPoly.java:115)

i have this error